# How do I remove specific child elements within an element of known ID?

Tags: javascript

I would like to be able to determine if a parent node, whose ID I know, has direct child  nodes, and if such nodes are detected, remove them.  The  nodes, if they exist, will always follow some text, so I don't think I can use firstChild or lastChild.

Ideally, I would use Javascript to minimize the performance hit.  Although JQuery would also work if necessary.

The code is like this:

```
<a id="anchorID">some text 
<span class="spanClass">some span text</span>
</a>
```

Any help, as always, is appreciated.

Comment: Using jQuery is a negligable performance hit, and will save you code and x-browser headaches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you'd like to remove the child nodes in your anchor, and you're ok with jQuery, then it's quite simply:

```
$("#anchorId").empty();
```

**EDIT**

You want to remove the span only?

```
$("#anchorID span").remove();
```

That will remove *all* spans in the anchor.  If you wanted to remove only the first span, then you could do

```
$("#anchorID span:first").remove();
```

Comment: @Adma Rackis Sorry, but I should have been more specific that I need to leave the anchor text intact.

Answer (score 3):

With jQuery and the HTML provided, it's as simple as `$("#anchorId").remove(".spanClass");`

Answer (score 2):

plain ol js

```
var target = document.getElementById("anchorId");
if(target.hasChildNodes())
{
  var children = new Array();
  children = target.childNodes();
  for(child in children)
  {
    target.removeChild[child];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With pure JavaScript use element.removeChild: http://jsfiddle.net/JetxN/

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like not to remove top level `textNode`s (i.e. "some text" anchor text):

```
$('#anchorID').children().remove();
```

- **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sXj7Y/)**